# extjs how to get selected html from textarea

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have extjs htmleditor with textarea. ANd i want to get selet html value.

Fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DCGRg/76/ - you can trigger event by entering something and adding styles and then clicking on the combobox at toolbar right.

i saw the code like that, but it's not getting me html, just text is getting:

```
content = selection.extractContents();
        //create span and wrap it around selection
        fontEl = document.createElement("span")
        fontEl.appendChild(content);
        text = fontEl.innerHTML
```

The question is: how to get html from textarea?

Answer (score 0):

InnerHTML only returns only the child contents, outerHTML is return with current note.
For Example:

"sample text" => using innerHTML => sample text 
"sample text" => using outterHTML => <span>sample
text</span>

I changed in your code innerHTML as outerHTML like bellow please check the [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/DCGRg/79/)

```
text = fontEl.outerHTML;
```